# Logo Design Critique

Tags: logo, text

[image: Explore text]

[image: Explore Skateshop text]

This logo is for a a board shop that sells handmade, handpainted longboards and skateboards. It is called Explore Skateshop

I wanted to make it obvious that this is indeed a boardshop so I made a vector of a longboard out of rectangles and circles. Then I added rounded squares as wheels.

I made a banner and added explore but need suggestions of how to integrate the skateshop/boardshop into the logo with good composition.

Would you care to give me some feedback about how this was executed? Anything to add or take away?

Comment: Brainstorming and idea gathering is not within the defined scope of this site, sorry.

Comment: How about feedback and critique? Sorry for my lack of clarity.

Comment: Please do not abuse tags. The fact that you used Adobe Illustrator to make this logo is irrelevant, as well as it being vector. Had you used Inkscape, the question and answers would be the same. The logo and text tags are sufficient.